# how to add query parameter to link url in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to add a query parameter to every links in pgae. the class of all link is `a-pg`.

I use this code for change but it not working:

```
$(".a-pg").attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+'?word=s');
```

I want to add `?word=s` to end of links.
can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this` in your context doesn't refer the anchor element

```
$(".a-pg").attr('href', function(_, href){
    return href+'?word=s'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uHP7z/)

Comment: that is the index of the current item, which we are not interested at

Comment: i know that but can we use _ as argument variable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".a-pg").each(function() {
   var newURL = $(this).attr('href')+'?'+ $.param({word : 's'});
   $(this).attr('href', newURL));
});
```

Check out the param() function documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param

Comment: this code return `admin/admin/search/page/6/undefined?word=s`